# UITableViewCell reordering style in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView which allows reordering. In all iOS versions before 11 the cell that is currently reordered is shown properly (just slightly transparent) while dragged.

In iOS 11 instead of the actual cell content, I see a white semi-transparent rectangle.

I searched everywhere but could not find a way to show the actual content. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was that while the cell is being dragged, all subviews of its `contentView` get a transparent background.

I fixed it by keeping a reference (as an `IBOutlet`) to my own background view and setting its `backgroundColor` in the cell's `layoutSubviews`. You can do the same for all other views whose `backgroundColor` you want to preserve.

```
class QuestionOrderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```